# Bluetooth keyboard keys unrecognized by Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard, bluetooth

I bought a new third party keyboard. It looks like my macbook built in one in terms of key order, but the 2 keys in the position of the usual <kbd>Cmd</kbd> don't work.

I know I can remap keys and put <kbd>Cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, but the point is that I can't use anyway these keys for whatever command.

How can I make use of these keys?

[image]

Comment: What is the keyboard model?

Comment: That's a very odd-looking 'windows' keyboard. ANSI (American-style) layout with EU specific details - possibly Italian. Normally, the 3rd modifier key on a Win keyboard is the "Windows" key, which, if used on a Mac, is interpreted as Cmd. Get hold of [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) from the App Store & see what it thinks that key should be.

Comment: ANSI Italian is definitely not standard, where did you get this?  Italian should be ISO, with the extra key next to Z and the different return key shape,  as shown in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794

Comment: Thank for the replies. I bought the keyboard here
[link](https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B07XYXLZS3/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

I was looking for a cheap and back keyboard with separated keys/buttons as apple ones.

@Tetsujin I tried with the key codes app but nothing happen if I click these keys nex to the space one :(

Comment: Well, it says it's for Android, so presumably Android devices will use that as the 'back' button. If KeyCodes can't see it at all, then neither can the Mac. I'd send it back & at least get a Windows one, if not a Mac one.